# POST to route not working, despite route displaying in "rake routes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following route, that appears in the list when I perform "rake routes":

```
         page_upload_image POST   /pages/:page_id/upload_image(.:format)                         pages#upload_image
```

I also have the following in my routes file:

```
resources :pages do
  post :sort, :on => :collection 
  post :upload_image, :on => :collection
end
```

I'm then using JavaScript to capture and POST values pulled from the following:

```
%form.new-page-image{:class => "hide", :action => "/pages/#{@page.id}/upload_image"}
  %input.page_image{:type => "file", :name => "page[image]", :multiple => "true"}
```

I have the following for my upload_image action in my pages controller:

```
def upload_image
  image = params[:page][:image]
  uploader = PageImageUploader.new
  uploader.store!(image)

  render json: uploader.to_json
end
```

For some reason, even though the route exists, when I post to it, I get the following:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/pages/1/upload_image"):
```

I'm wondering why a route, that appears legitimate (shows up properly when executing rake routes) would return this error when I try to post to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your routes to this instead, as it looks like you want a member route instead of a collection route:

```
resources :pages do
  post :sort, :on => :collection 
  post :upload_image, :on => :member
end
```

I would also advise against using interpolation in the route, as it can quickly get long and messy. Instead try to name your routes using `as:` and call them using the names instead.